# Is there a panel in HTML?

Tags: html

In .NET you have a panel object.

[image]

This gives you a border, as well as a label, which is good for grouping objects.

Is there a similar device in HTML? I assumed there was, but my google-fu is failing me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fieldset` tag is used a group box or panel to surround form elements. You can use a `legend` element for the caption.

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Edit Method Based Query</legend>
    <label for="methodName">Method name: </label><input id="methodName"  .. >
    
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3):

A [fieldset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp) is the nearest equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

HTML has `fieldset`. Here is an example from [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

```html
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Title</legend>
        <input type="input" name="radio" id="radio"> <label for="radio">Enter text</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean div, section or article elements in HTML like this?

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp

or

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

this?